# When merging pull request, commit appears on GitHub that doesn't exist locally

Tags: git, github

## Setup

I have just created a pull request on GitHub with the following two parents:

`2 parents: 184... + 3fb...`:

- `184` is the very last commit on master, had also bee pushed to
  `origin/master`
- `3fb` is the very last commit on my feature branch.

`3fb` is the very last commit on my feature branch.

I am running TravisCI and noticed that this is actually being run twice for each new PR, in this case it was run for `3fb` (from above) and some new commit, which I assume is the combination of `184` and `3fb` - let's say this has commit hash `68b`.

## Problem

When I click Merge and pull down the resulting master branch, I expect to see `68b`, but instead I'm seeing a new one (for completion's sake, it's `a64`). I do not see `68b` locally anywhere!

When I try to check out `68b` locally, I get `fatal: reference is not a tree: 68b`.

What's going on technically here? Why do I never get this commit locally?

Answer (score 2):

The details vary from one CI system to another, but in general, CI systems build a specific commit.  A GitHub *pull request* may not have a commit yet.<sup>1</sup>  So presumably Travis-CI in this case made *its own* commit, which it then tested successfully.  That was the `68b` you observed.

[**Edit**: [GoodDeeds commented that Travis-CI does use the trial merge that GitHub makes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60979846/when-merging-pull-request-commit-appears-on-github-that-doesnt-exist-locally/60981957?noredirect=1#comment107888596_60981957), which wrecks this particular theory.  But there are still several ways to get the same result.]

> When I click Merge ...

Since this happens on GitHub itself (not on Travis), GitHub now make *their own* commit(s).  Since every commit has a totally-unique hash ID, this one *won't* be `68b`.  **Edit**:  Or, if GitHub may make a new commit every time, instead of re-using the trial merge they made earlier.

> ... and pull down the resulting master branch, I expect to see `68b`, but instead I'm seeing a new one (for completion's sake, it's `a64`). I do not see `68b` locally anywhere!

Presumably, then, the one *GitHub* made, upon clicking the button, starts with `a64`.  (The uniqueness constraint results in the long and too-hard-to-deal-with full hash IDs.  Git will let you abbreviate as long as the result is unambiguous, but the actual minimum is 4 characters, not the 3 you have used here.)

You can tell GitHub not to do a regular merge, but instead to do either a squash-merge or a rebase-and-merge.  Neither of these use any existing merge commit, so both of these actions *always* result in a new, unique hash ID that your own Git has never seen before.

---

<sup>1</sup>Some GitHub PRs do, and some do not.  If GitHub did make a merge, that commit is available from GitHub.  Other hosting systems may behave somewhat differently and some CI systems may not *use* the potentially-tentative-anyway commit that GitHub may or may not have made at this point, choosing to just make their own.  While I have used Travis-CI, I've never investigated it enough to know precisely what it does here.

Comment: Travis-CI seems to do `git fetch origin +refs/pull/<PR-number>/merge:` to get the PR locally.

Comment: @GoodDeeds: OK, so that's a trial merge that GitHub made. If the Merge button uses the trial merge, you'll get the same hash ID again, so if the Merge button is making a new merge, then either GitHub is making a new merge now (certainly possible) or the OP has the merge button set up to do a rebase-and-merge or squash-and-merge.

Comment: Thank you both! Upvoted but still slightly confused on one point I guess. Shouldn't the trees be the same both on GitHub and locally? I can still access this trial merge via the GitHub website (github.com/commits/68b.... or something like that). Does this mean that the trial merge may not live in the tree that I'm fetching, even though its parents are? Thanks again for your thoughts!

Comment: The word "tree" is badly overloaded in computing, so I'll answer that with this: The internal *tree* object associated with the two different commits is probably the same one each time, but the two commits are different. A Git hash ID specifies one Git object; commits always have a unique hash ID, which Git enforces by putting time stamps into commits, so that if they're otherwise identical, they differ in the time-stamp. (Tree objects and blob objects don't have this feature and do get re-used.)